# Mocking class with multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, interface, moq

I am trying to test a method that is using two different interfaces.
Using Moq I configure the interfaces methods and set a return object, but just the first method executed returns value, the second returns null, no matter what I set as Returns.

This is an example :

Interface 1

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetUserById(int id);
}
```

Interface 2

```
public interface ICallApiService
{
    ApiResponseDto ValidateUser();
}
```

Class I want to test

```
public class UserServices : IUserServices
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private ICallApiService _callApiService;

    public UserServices(IUserRepository userRepository, ICallApiService callApiService)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _callApiService = callApiService;
    }
    public User GetUserById(int id)
    {
        //result always have a value set to result
        var result = _callApiService.ValidateUser();

        //result2 is always null
        var result2 = _userRepository.GetUserById(result.UserId);

        return result2;
    }

}
```

The Test Method

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    moqUserRepository = new Moq.Mock<IUserRepository>();
    moqUserRepository.Setup(s => s.GetUserById(1)).Returns(new User() { Id = 100, Birth = DateTime.Now, Email = "g@test.com", Name="g" });

    moqCallApiService = new Moq.Mock<ICallApiService>();
    moqCallApiService.Setup(s => s.ValidateUser()).Returns(new ApiResponseDto() { Active = true, Messages = "None", UserId = 100 });


    var userService = new UserServices(moqUserRepository.Object, moqCallApiService.Object);
    var resultInstance = userService.GetUserById(1);

    var moqUserService = new Moq.Mock<UserServices>(moqUserRepository.Object, moqCallApiService.Object).Object;
    var resultMock = moqUserService.GetUserById(1);

}
```

In both cases using instance and mock i get the same error (return null).

Am I missing something to Moq ?

Comment: Where are you setting up your `moqUserService`  to return something for `GetUserById()`?

Comment: So you're expecting `moqUserService.GetUserById` to return a value when you haven't mocked that method?

Comment: Why are you mocking `UserServices` in the last part?

Comment: For Mocking don't use specific parameter values, always use generic Any integer value, so it returns same thing for any input value

Comment: @MatthewWatson You are correct, it was missing on my test. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG you are correct I was missing it when configuring Mock to my service class. But my problem was that the moqUserRepository.GetUserById wasn't returning any value. That was my mistake because I set the parameter to  GetUserById  as 1, not 100 or It.IsAny<int>().

Comment: Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen Just trying to get it to work.

Comment: Mrinal Kamboj  You are totally correct. It was the base of my error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're instructing the repository mock to return an object when the input parameter `id` has the value 1. But the service code calls the repository with the value of `result.UserId` which is set to be 100 by the other mock setup call.

Change the first setup call to

```
moqUserRepository.Setup(s => s.GetUserById(100)).Returns(new User() { Id = 100, Birth = DateTime.Now, Email = "g@test.com", Name="g" });
```

Or use `It.IsAny`, since you don't really care about the value when you only have a single mocked call to the method:

```
moqUserRepository.Setup(s => s.GetUserById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new User() { Id = 100, Birth = DateTime.Now, Email = "g@test.com", Name="g" });
```

Comment: `It.IsAny<int>()` shall be the preferred approach not the hard coded values

Comment: Thank you. I was totally missing that.